# Word is not opening any files! Anyone know what this could be?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to open word documents and get greeted with this now. Any idea what it can be? Restarting my pc did not help! it is a surface book 2[image: just shows docx icon]

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a paid version of MS Office, try to remove it through the control panel, and delete all related files with it. After that, use a clean installation and use your key again in order to have your MS Office package working again.

If this not work for you, respond here and we will find another solution.

Comment: «try to remove it through the control panel, and delete all related files with it. After that, use a clean installation» This is rarely necessary. Ever heard of an Office repair? In any event, this is not a programming question and is therefore off-topic for StackOverflow,